# Laravel Localization dropdown in blade

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am trying to implement laravel localization.

What I do is this code:

```
<select class="form-control" onchange="location = this.value;">

  @if(session() -> get('locale') == 'it')
  <option value="{{ url('locale/it') }}"> IT</option>
  <option value="{{ url('locale/en') }}">EN</option>
  <option value="{{ url('locale/de') }}"> DE</option>
  @elseif(session() -> get('locale') == 'en')
  <option value="{{ url('locale/en') }}">EN</option>
  <option value="{{ url('locale/it') }}"> IT</option>
  <option value="{{ url('locale/de') }}"> DE</option>
  @elseif(session() -> get('locale') == 'de')
  <option value="{{ url('locale/de') }}"> DE</option>
  <option value="{{ url('locale/en') }}">EN</option>
  <option value="{{ url('locale/it') }}"> IT</option>
  @endif
</select>
```

It works but when I see in another browser I can not click on dropdown cause there is no data to click. Is this because of the session? What should I do in this case?

Comment: Can you elaborate on `when I see next day`? I can't seem to understand what is your problem

Comment: @Charlie Because of the session.  When i open it in another browser I can not see the values of dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
@if ( Config::get('app.locale') == 'it') 
@elseif ( Config::get('app.locale') == 'en' )
@elseif ( Config::get('app.locale') == 'de' )
@endif
```